# error MSB3073: reported by Visual Studio 2013 Post-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2013, exit-code

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to run a suite of unit tests, which all pass.

If I run the tests as part of a post-build event they still pass but Visual Studio reports the following error:

```
Test Suite passed
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: The command "MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\bash run-test-suite.sh "TestSuiteName" test-dir Debug test-suite
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.92
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. I haven't been able to find any explanation of what can cause an exit code of -1.

One of the unit tests causes the class-under-test to throw an exception which it catches itself - i.e. it is not propagated to the test. While investigating the problem I noted that if I prevent the exception from being thrown the error goes away.

Comment: Removed the bash tag. Was added in error.

Comment: Well, it wasn't, it was bash that exited with exit code -1.  Why you are using bash when you say that you are using VS2013 to run unit tests is very hard to reverse-engineer.  Stop using bash, perhaps.

Comment: The post-build event in Visual Studio invokes a bash script to execute the tests. What does exit code -1 mean?

Comment: It is Unix-style error reporting for "It did not work".